# Many-to-many association in doctrine to existing Symfony form field types

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to have a entity which stores surveys containing questions of different types (extending `AbstractType`).

#### Method 1

So I want the `Survey` entity to have a list of questions, some `TextareaType` and some `ChoiceType`. My entity has two fields for each of these collections:

```
private $choice_questions; // Doctrine ArrayCollection mapped to entity extending ChoiceType
private $text_questions; // Doctrine ArrayCollection mapped to entity extending TextareaType
```

I plan to map these two fields with a many-to-many association to entities extending one of the existing form field types in Symfony: The [`TextareaType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html) and [`ChoiceType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)

#### Method 2

I could have a generic `Questions` entity as a [custom form field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) with a `$type` field which is used to define the field type in the `getParent()` method:

```
public function getParent()
{
    if($this->type == 1)
    return ChoiceType::class;
    else if($this->type == 2)
    return TextareaType::class;
}
```

There would be only one field storing a list of questions in my `Survey` entity which is mapped to this generic `Questions` entity:

```
private $questions; // Doctrine ArrayCollection mapped to Questions entity (many-to-many)
```

Which approach do you think is better when it comes to building the form in the `Survey` class?

Comment: Seems like a great case for Doctrine inheritance

Comment: @JasonRoman No, I can't use that since the EasyAdmin bundle I'm using to manage these entites does not support doctrine inheritance. Plus Doctrine doesn't handle inheritance very well either.